# Visuall Studio Tabs Are So Small, How To Magnify Them?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

In Visual Studio, it is very hard to pass to another tab. You can't Alt+1, Alt+2 to pass to another tab, and you can Ctrl+Tab to pass but it is slow, and the tab sizes are soooooo small that it is really hard to click on them. Zooming on font sizes don't help. And I couldn't find an answer online.

Could you tell me how to make the tabs bigger, so that I can easily click on them?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2019-16.8.6
Here is a screenshot of what I want:

[image: Tabs]

Comment: Which tabs are you talking about?  A screenshot might help explain your question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung added.

Comment: So to clarify: 1) you mean the VStudio IDE tabs, right?  And 2) you mean in Visual Studio, and *not* VSCode?  (you have both tags on your question)  If so, then what version?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I edited accordingly, I was asking for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension to set tabs font size:

[image]

And assign shortcuts to pass to a tab by number:
https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/addins/navigator.html

Comment: The cost is $49 US for a *personal* license.

Comment: It is not free, this is a big problem. I cant give money just to magnify tabs

Answer (score 7):

This is tricky to find, primarily because most of us don't realize (or forget) that the Fonts and Colors dialog has a "Show settings for:" selector at the top.

So, to change it, from the VS IDE menu:

1. Select `Tools -> Options..`,
2. Click on `Environment..Fonts and Colors` in the Options Explorer (the pane on the left-hand side)
3. At the top center is a grayed-out dropdown titled "Show settings for:", select `Environment` from this,
4. Set "Display Items:" to `Plain Text`, then use the "Fonts" dropdown to change it from `Automatic` to whatever font and size you want.

[image]

Comment: Note that unfortunately this changes the entire interface, not only the tabs. Also note that if all you want is to increase the font size and not change the font, the standard UI font is Segoe UI since Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Install the Visual Studio extension [Font Sizer 2.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FontSizer2). Then you will be presented with the ability to *quickly* change it via the keyboard or menu option:

[image]

Results (Before/After) after resizing.:

[image]

---

As to tab switching, I've been using `Alt` -> `Tab` which switches immediately back to the previous window. If you hold the keystroke chord, it will give you a list of open editor windows and you can move within the list or even select via a mouse.